# Sort list of numbers as strings with more than one decimal point in Java

Tags: java, android

i'm trying to sort this ArrayList:

```
["1","1.1","1.2","1.3","2.1","2.3","4","4.1","6","7.1","8","8.1","10.1","2.4.7","2.2","2.4.8","3","2.4.2","2.4.9","2.4.5","5","5.1","7","2.4.4","2.4.6","2.4.1","2","2.4","3.1","6.1","9","9.1","10","11","11.1","12","12.1","13","2.4.3"]
```

i used `Collections.sort()`, but it's working only with decimals less than 10, because when an item has more than 10 decimals sort for the value in number but not in list order. For example a list from 1.1 to 1.14 the result is this:

```
1.1, 1.10, 1.11, 1.12, 1.13, 1.14, 1.2, 1.3, ... 1.8, 1.9
```

but should be like this:

```
1.1, 1.2, 1.3, ... 1.9, 1.10, 1.11, 1.12, 1.13, 1.14
```

And only with one decimal point.

Finally the result it should have is:

```
["1","1.1","1.2","1.3","2","2.1","2.2","2.3","2.4","2.4.1","2.4.2","2.4.3","2.4.4","2.4.5","2.4.6","2.4.7","2.4.8","2.4.9","3","3.1","4","4.1","5","5.1","6","6.1","7","7.1","8","8.1","9","9.1 ","10","10.1","11","11.1","12","12.1","13"]
```

I accept any suggestion.

Thanks

Comment: Try making a custom sort.

Comment: Your numbers are strings, so you are sorting them alphabetically instead of numerically. Also, what is the stuff like `"2.4.5"`?

Comment: Maybe it is the best to make tuples/arrays of each string with 3 elements. And sort primarily by first element, then by second, then by third.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with implementing your own custom comparator:

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    @Override
    public int compare(String version1, String version2) {
        String[] parts1 = splitByParts(version1);
        String[] parts2 = splitByParts(version2);

        for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(parts1.length, parts2.length); i++) {
            int partComparison = compareParts(parts1[i], parts2[i]);
            if (partComparison != 0) {
                return partComparison;
            }
        }
        return Integer.compare(parts1.length, parts2.length);
    }

    protected String[] splitByParts(String version) {
        return version.split("\\.");
    }

    private int compareParts(String firstPart, String secondPart) {
        int firstPartValue = Integer.parseInt(firstPart);
        int secondPartValue = Integer.parseInt(secondPart);
        return Integer.compare(firstPartValue, secondPartValue);

    }
}
```

And then just call:

```
String[] arr = {"1", "1.1", "1.2", "1.3", "2.1", "2.3", "4", "4.1", "6", "7.1", "8", "8.1", "10.1", "2.4.7", "2.2", "2.4.8", "3", "2.4.2", "2.4.9", "2.4.5", "5", "5.1", "7", "2.4.4", "2.4.6", "2.4.1", "2", "2.4", "3.1", "6.1", "9", "9.1", "10", "11", "11.1", "12", "12.1", "13", "2.4.3"};
Arrays.sort(arr, new CustomComparator());
for (String s : arr) {
       System.out.println(s);
}
```

Please note that this is sorting in place.