# Problem sorting Mediastore track number containing String values

Tags: android, sql, android-room, android-contentprovider, mediastore

I want to sort playlists by track_numbers. I receive these track_numbers by querying Android `Mediastore` column `MediaStore.Audio.Media.TRACK`.
Android returns a string value, so track_numbers in mp3 files set like `1 from 35` or `1/35` will handelt as Strings. Sorting these values I got a list like "1,10,11,100,101,...2,..".
I want to get values sorted like Integers (e.g: "1,2,3,4,...").

In Android < 10 I handel this with an SQL correction while querying like `...order by cast(track_name as unsigned)`.
In Android >= 10 this correction doesn't work.

Can someone give me a tip on how to solve the problem?

Thanks
Alejandro

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61944310/sort-list-of-numbers-as-strings-with-more-than-one-decimal-point-in-java

Comment: not really, because it also could receive Strings from `MediaStore.Audio.Media.TRACK`  like Italien or French "1 de 75". I don't understand why my solution useing an SQL ORDER BY works below android 10 and with Android 10 not.

Comment: I would query `Mediastore` at the same way like You posted (Cast...).

Comment: @GGK Thanks...that worked, Great!